# How to return whole sql query data?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, reactjs, flask

Right now my code only returns lastrowid but I want to know how to return the whole object from my backend when I insert the new product to my backend(python, flask and MySQL).
Frontend is in ReactJS.

POST product route:

```
@app.route('/product', methods=['POST'])
def insert_product():
    request_payload = request.json
    product_id = products_dao.insert_new_product(connection, request_payload)
    response = jsonify({
        'product_id': product_id
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response
```

insert_new_product function

```
def insert_new_product(connection, product):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query=("insert into products (name, uom_id, price_per_unit) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
    data = (product['product_name'],product['uom_id'], product['price_per_unit'])
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    connection.commit()
    return cursor.lastrowid
```

Right now insert_new_product return only lastrowid so I need to refresh my website to get the complete object.

the complete object looks like this.
[image]

But I get this object when I add a new product from the frontend.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the row just inserted you could use the `lastrowid` in a query to get it

```
cursor.execute("select * from products where product_id = %s", (cursor.lastrowid,))
print(cursor.fetchone()) # returns result as tuple
```

But I don't think you even need to do this since you already have the data you want `request_payload` + the `product_id`.

So you could keep most of the code the same as in the question and change `response` from this

```
response = jsonify({'product_id': product_id})
```

to something like this

```
request_payload["product_id"] = product_id
response = jsonify(request_payload)
```